# Convert a string into an Array SQL/Snowflake?dbt

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have the following column with a string per row:

country=US&lan=EN&retailer=nike&retailer=addidas&retailer=puma

And I want to extract the country, lan and retailer, so at the end I will have:

| country | lan | retailer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | EN | [nike, addidas puma] |

Any one knows how to do that in sql or dbt?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way using [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html), [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html), [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html)

```
SELECT listagg(iff(key='country',value, null)) as country,
    listagg(iff(key='lan',value, null)) as lan,
    array_agg(iff(key='retailer',value, null)) as retailer
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SPLIT_PART(s.value,'=', 1) as key,
        SPLIT_PART(s.value,'=', 2) as value
    FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('country=US&lan=EN&retailer=nike&retailer=addidas&retailer=puma','&')) s
)
```

gives:

| COUNTRY | LAN | RETAILER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | EN | [ "nike", "addidas", "puma" ] |

but it depends how you want to handle multiple countries (same or different)  etc etc. I suspect it will not end up what you want.

But if you want a similar pattern per row:

```
SELECT listagg(iff(key='country',value, null)) as country,
    listagg(iff(key='lan',value, null)) as lan,
    array_agg(iff(key='retailer',value, null)) as retailer
FROM (
    SELECT s.seq,
        SPLIT_PART(s.value,'=', 1) as key,
        SPLIT_PART(s.value,'=', 2) as value
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM VALUES
         ('country=US&lan=EN&retailer=nike&retailer=addidas&retailer=puma'), 
         ('country=AU&lan=EN&retailer=nike&retailer=addidas&retailer=puma')
    ), TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(column1,'&')) s
) GROUP BY seq
ORDER BY SEQ
```

gives:

| COUNTRY | LAN | RETAILER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | EN | [ "nike", "addidas", "puma" ] |
| AU | EN | [ "nike", "addidas", "puma" ] |

Answer (score 0):

These look like url parameters. I would try dbt util's `get_url_parameter` macro (see [docs](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_url_parameter-source))

```
select
    {{ dbt_utils.get_url_parameter(field='your_string_field', url_parameter='country') }} as country,
    {{ dbt_utils.get_url_parameter(field='your_string_field', url_parameter='lan') }} as lan,
    {{ dbt_utils.get_url_parameter(field='your_string_field', url_parameter='retailer') }} as retailer
from your_table
```